# WPF Binding question

Tags: wpf, binding

I have a question regarding the binding

I have two textbox, textbox one is bind to the property NAME and has the tag  FULLName

<  TextBox Name="NewTextBox" Tag="FullName" Text="{Binding Path = Name}" >

In the second textbox I need to bind to the property that is available as the tag on the first textbox.

How to do it in XAML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<TextBox Name="NewTextBox" Tag="FullName" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" /> 
<TextBox x:Name="NewTextBox2" Text="{Binding ElementName=NewTextBox, Path=Tag}"/>
```

Comment: i want to bind to the Fullname property in the datacontext.
But i need to get the property from the tag of the NewTextbox.

Comment: In such a case, set the data context of the NewTextBox2 to FullName and set the binding path to Tag of the element name.   

Similar to the snippet that I have mentioned above but the addition would be setting up of the DataContext for NewTextBox2

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but is this what you're looking for?

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox1" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" Tag="{Binding Path=FullName}"/>
<TextBox x:Name="textbox2" Text="{Binding ElementName=textbox1, Path=Tag}"/>
```